# Is it okay to re-assign the struct variable more than once?

Tags: c#

So, here I have some variables initialized like this.

```
var center = Vector2.Zero; // For sample purpose, the real one gain the value dynamically.
var size = 1F;
var sizeHalf = size / 2; // The `size` variable will be like readonly after initialization in my project.
var angle = 30F;
var anCos = Mathf.Cos(angle);
var anSin = Mathf.Sin(angle);
```

> For the detail, `Vector2` is a `struct` and **NOT** a `class`.

And I have four `Vector2` variables that I initialized like this.

```
var b = new Vector2 (center.x , center.y - sizeHalf);
var t = new Vector2 (center.x , center.y + sizeHalf);
var l = new Vector2 (center.x - sizeHalf , center.y);
var r = new Vector2 (center.x + sizeHalf , center.y);
// Re-assign to get the adjusted values
b = new Vector2 (b.x , (b.x * anCos) + (b.y * anSin));
t = new Vector2 (t.x , (t.x * anCos) + (t.y * anSin));
l = new Vector2 ((l.x * anCos) - (l.y * anSin) , l.y);
r = new Vector2 ((r.x * anCos) - (r.y * anSin) , r.y);
```

So, back to my question,

- Is doing a variable <strike>initialization more than once</strike> re-assignment like that good approach and okay?
- If it's not, should I just do something like this?

  ```
  // Temporary variable to store most used calculated variable
  var pB = center.y - sizeHalf;
  var pT = center.y + sizeHalf;
  var pL = center.x - sizeHalf;
  var pR = center.x + sizeHalf;
  var b = new Vector2 (center.x, (center.x * anCos) + (pB * anSin));
  var t = new Vector2 (center.x, (center.x * anCos) + (pT * anSin));
  var l = new Vector2 ((pL * anCos) - (center.y * anSin), center.y);
  var r = new Vector2 ((pR * anCos) - (center.y * anSin), center.y);
  ```
- Or is there any good approach than I mentioned above?

Thanks.

EDIT :
Here, in my code I use `var` instead of their real `TypeName`, that's because I wrote this code inside a function and just used in that scope, even more smaller scope (in that function, I have some `if`s and it's only used inside that `if`) and for the simplicity and faster variable writing, it's a simple function so I think using `var` is plenty.

Comment: Could you just MODIFY the member vars X and Y of the existing stuct and choose not to create a new stuct to re-initialize with the new key word.  Is not that the point of a struct in .net?

Comment: @SqlSurfer: Absolutely not, that is a *terrible* programming practice. Structs should be immutable in C# unless there is a very, very good reason to make them mutable.

Comment: Eric - I think you go to the heart of why this question intrigues me.  Is this one of the cases where lazy garbage collection is a benefit?

Comment: @SqlSurfer: I don't understand what you're talking about. None of the values in this example are collected in the first place. Which value in this example do you believe is being managed by the garbage collector?

Comment: Is there a reason why you feel the need to comment that those variables are floats?  If you think that's necessary for the reader to understand the program then **do not use var in the first place**.  var is for cases where it is easy to understand the type of the variable, or where the type is not relevant.

Comment: @EricLippert well, sorry, but the reason I use `var` is in my project it's only used in that scope, and I actually know what type it is, and the `// Single/Float` is actually not in my project, just in case someone read this and don't know about var in C#, so sorry.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is doing a variable initialization more than once ...

First off, let's use words correctly. It is incoherent to ask what happens when you *initialize* something *twice* because by definition, the *initial value* is assigned *the initial time the variable is assigned*. That is, the *first* time.

By the time the second assignment rolls around, the variable is already *initialized*; the second assignment doesn't initialize it again; **it already has its initial value**.

But you meant to say "assigned", I understand.

> Is doing a variable assignment more than once like that good approach and okay in terms of memory and performance?

Seems fine to me.

Are you experiencing memory or performance problems?

If you are, this is not one of the places I would look at first. **I would use a profiler to examine my memory and performance characteristics**.

Since performance is almost certainly irrelevant, the question you should have asked is:

> Is the second technique, using single assignment form, better in some other way?

Yes.  **You should use single assignment form**, where every variable is assigned *once* if reasonably possible.

The reason has nothing to do with memory or performance. The reason is because it is much easier to read, understand, debug and maintain code where the variables don't change often.  A variable that changes only once, when it is initialized, is ideal. You never need to wonder what value it used to have, you never need to wonder how many times it has been mutated, and you can give your variables descriptive names the meanings of which do not change as control progresses through your method.

Comment: Ah, I see, well I have twisted `term` in my brain right now (as Initialize and assigned) so I'm sorry for that.

Comment: So, if I re-assign the variable using new "initialization?" like the sample above is actually not a bad form but using single assignment form is better, right? But I'm a bit curious, is the re-assign process is just replace the variable directly (also in memory)?

Comment: Gotta love the concept of non varying variables; perhaps a better term could be found for such things.

Comment: @Richard: In Java they're called "final local variables". It's a nice feature that C# could pick up; C# already has readonly fields that can only change in a constructor.  And in the ML family of languages, variables are all single assignment by default; there's a special syntax for mutable variables.

Answer (score -1):

It is absolutely OK.
First option is better in terms of amount of variables in stack.

Comment: Is there some reason why it would be a good idea to optimize stack usage? Stack is cheap.

Comment: not a big deal. But there should be a reason to introduce second set of variables. After second assignment you have 8 variables, but you only need 4.  First 4 do not have sense. Consider situation if you doing 10 times more recalculations and at the end you need only 4 variables, not 40.

Comment: Is there some reason to want to have fewer variables? Variables are cheap. If you have 40 concepts then make 40 variables, don't make 4 variables and mutate them 10 times each so that their meaning changes throughout the method.  Optimize for the right thing: **minimize the mental energy it takes to understand a program**. That means *more explanatory variables*, not fewer.

Comment: This function needs only 4 variables = at any moment this function exists in 4-dimensional space. You are adding 4 more dimensions to it = making it twice more complicated. At the end topic starter has only 4 variables for further calculations, but you have 8 variables. For example, with 8 variables you can make a typo and return pB instead of b, that is exactly the result of twice more dimensions.

Comment: Which is precisely why those are terrible names. Variables names should be long and descriptive, so that they represent their semantics, and so that you cannot easily mistake one for the other.

Comment: anyway with 4 variables you have to worry about names twice less.

Comment: I will ask you from another side: Why do you want to have values of first calculation? Why do you need them? I mean, you put 4 allocation instructions and making this function stack to have 4 more variables. For what exactly?

Comment: To **avoid writing a lie into the program**.  Take the variable "b" for example. Plainly it is intended to represent the bottom of something. But in the original code, for *half of its lifetime* it's a lie; it's a *temporary variable that will be used to compute the real bottom*. If that's what it is, then *say it*. Don't make the reader figure it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167058/discussion-between-eugene-gorbovoy-and-eric-lippert).